# Are Brahmins allowed to use non-cow leather products?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras, brahmins, ahimsa

Are Brahmins allowed to use non-cow leather products? Obtaining leather involves ahimsa, but many things Brahmins already use involve ahimsa like silk (killing worms alive), deerskin for Brahmacharis, etc. so I'm wondering if leather products (non-cow) are allowed.

Comment: Silk is supposed to be Madi vasthara but regarding himsa it should be abondened same holds for deer skin.. where ever we see himsa to other life form should be avoided in this regard Kanchi maha periyava refused to wear slik vastara after coming to know of process.. and he refused tiger skin given by devotee as it committed out of killing the animal.. but eventually relented based on devotee insistence.. but he didnt use it always.

Comment: ahimsa versions of all these products are available - ahimsa pattu (silk), ahimsa then (honey), ahimsa maanthool (deerskin).. but it costs money, time & effort to find them. so people go for commercial alternatives. where there is will, there is way

Comment: @mar It is easy to speak big but people will listen to big words only if the speaker implements it in real life.

Comment: @AnubrataBit - correct, the power of preacher is not in his words, but in his practice. if it's hard to get ahimsa version, it is easier to atleast avoid himsa version.

Comment: @mar Are you talking about artificial leather, artificial silk, etc?

Comment: @Ikshvaku - no. ahimsa silk is derived from coccons that naturally leave their shell, instead of killing them while alive. i'm not aware of any ahimsa leather where they only collect hide of naturally dead animals.

Comment: @mar Can you provide the name of a manufacturer that sells ahimsa silk?

Comment: in pondi bazaar in chennai during some months, a khadi exhibition used to be held. but u can try asking higher-ups in any silk shop, they might have contacts.